# Passing variable from command handler

Tags: c#

I have a following method in my command handler that gets variables from another method,im trying to pass those variable into the `CreateUser(NewAccount);` method but it always comes back as `null`

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(CreateUserAccountCommand command)
{
    var result = await _client.CreateUser(GetAccountFrom(command)); // so this line gets the variables from GetAccountFrom(command) 
   _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["CreateUserAccountCommand"] = result;
}

private Account GetAccountFrom(CreateUserAccountCommand command)
{
    var NewAccount = new Account();
    NewAccount.FirstName = command.FirstName;
    NewAccount.LastName = command.LastName;
    return NewAccount()
}
```

however when i call `CreateUser` to pass in the variables into NewAccount thats coming from `GetAccountFrom(command)` it passes it in as a `null`

```
 public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Account> CreateUser(Account NewAccount,)
 {
     return base.Channel.CreateUser(NewAccount);
 }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is that **exactly** how you code looks? Especially this line `return NewAccount()`

Comment: It is not. because there a lot of syntax errors. It has been copied and modified pasted to protect IP.. lol

Comment: [mcve] desperately needed for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `NewAccount` in your return statement.

```
private Account GetAccountFrom(CreateUserAccountCommand command)
{
     var newAccount = new Account();

     newAccount.FirstName = command.FirstName;
     newAccount.LastName = command.LastName;
     return newAccount; // <- Return the variable
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it have been return `return new Account()` if that was the case?

Comment: There is no `new` key word. I mean that should have compile time blew up, unless its implicitly converting that to an anonymous function task.. ?

Comment: @Magnus Well there should also be a `;` at the end of the line, so I simply guessed that the code wasn't copied, but rather rewritten for the question and the space disappeared.

Comment: There must be a method NewAccount somewhere because I copied that into myu Visual studio and I get a compile error. `Method Name Expected`

Comment: Also that wouldn't have caused `null` to be passed to `CreateUser()`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating object with `new` keyword. All you need to do is to return this object from your method with simple call:

```
return NewAccount;
```

The way you do it now is that you are returning *result* of `NewAccount()` method (whatever it is, apparently `null`), which is not what you want.

Also you might want to inspect why `NewAccount()` returns always `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many anti patterns but it seems like you have a method somewhere in the base `newAccount();` This is why inheritance should be avoided (for beginners and mids)

also the convention for private local variables lowercase.. as to NOT CONFUSE yourself.

```
private Account GetAccountFrom(CreateUserAccountCommand command)
{
    var newAccount = new Account();
    newAccount.FirstName = command.FirstName;
    newAccount.LastName = command.LastName;
    return newAccount;
}
```

or to completely avoid confusion just do this

```
private Account GetAccountFrom(CreateUserAccountCommand command)
{
    return new Account{
        FirstName = command.FirstName,
        LastName = command.LastName,
    }
}
```

But to avoid anti-patterns and spaghetti code you should really make an extension method which is much more S.O.L.I.D !

```
namespace you.company
{
  public static CommandExtensions{
    public static Account GetAccountFrom(this CreateUserAccountCommand command)
    {
        return new Account
        {
            FirstName = command.FirstName,
            LastName = command.LastName,
        };
    }
}
```